# SpringBoot REST API many-to-many, I want to fetch all members in Team

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, maven

My "team" endpoint is working fine , I'm getting response from rest client, however I'm not able to retrieve members inside each team.

My Json File looks something like this:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "teamName": "OUTLIERS",
    "year": 2021,
    "teamLead": {
              "name":"bbb",
               "status":"ABC"
}, "members":[
{},{},{}
]
```

Team End Point :

```
    @GetMapping(path = **"/{id}/members")**
    public List<Member> getTeamMembers(@PathVariable Long id) {

        //System.out.println(team.getMembers().size());
        List<Member> members = teamRepo.getOne(id).getMembers();
        return members;
    }

// ----- Member Pojos ---

package org.itpn.web.pojos;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class MemberVO {

private Long memberId;

String firstName;

String lastName;

String membershipId;

Long primaryPhone;

String whatsappPhone;

String emailAddress;

boolean active;
    
}
```

In the above code root directory is "/teams" , I'm trying to fetch members from teams/id/members resource.

Comment: Can you share the repo?

Comment: It looks like a lazy initialization of the members field on your Team entity, but need more context. Do you use database and Hibernate?

Comment: @VitalyKolesnikov Yes, fetch type is = Lazy, and I'm using Mysql and Spring Hibernate.

Comment: ` @Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "teams")
public class Team {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "team_id")
 private Long id;

 @Column(name = "team_name")
 String teamName;
 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST},fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinTable(name = "member_teams", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "member_id"))
 //@JsonIgnore
 private List<Member> members;
}
 `

Comment: Writing code in comments section is not a good idea. Please upload your project to Github and give a link. So everybody could see the whole project in the IDE and find the problem.

Comment: Thanks @VitalyKolesnikov , Sure I'll share the project link, meanwhile I'll test your query.

Comment: Adding Project Links:[link](https://github.com/SJMcode/idara/blob/a069b3ef8a3284568a775df0bc659b4eb3ef35c0/src/main/java/org/itpn/web/endpoints/TeamEndPoint.java)

Comment: Above link leads to 404 :/

Comment: Here is the correct link : https://github.com/SJMcode/Test.git

Answer (score 0):

As by information given so far I suggest to create a method getTeamWithMembers(Long id) in repository with HQL query like this:

```
select t from Team t left join fetch t.members
```

Comment: It's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try fetch type - eager as fetch = FetchType.EAGER

Comment: tried but not working, any other suggestions: Project lik -> https://github.com/SJMcode/Test.git

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it`s too many questions.

It's ridiculous how you uploaded your code (all classes in one file) and it doesn`t look as Spring applocation at all.

Why do you have repository dependencies in your controller and not service?

Why do you need MemberVO (I suppose it is DTO?) if your controller method returns List of Member entity?

So anyway, I created a test project and made a refactoring and uploaded it to Github. It works and returns teams with members. You can download it and change whatever you need.

https://github.com/VitalyKolesnikov/Teams

Comment: Now I can access members - Thanks a lot for your help, I can't share complete project as it's private one, I shared those class files where I had difficulties. MemberVO - this class somehow I want to inject as I don't want complete info from actual member entity in Database.

Comment: You can add method 'MemberVO fromMember(Member member)' to MemberVO class, which will map the entity to DTO. And then call this method in controller and return your DTO.